# Delete path of two anchor points, but not the anchors themselves

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

I am trying to change the path of a two anchors. I have tried grouping the two anchors I do not want connecting together and goto Object>Path>Divide Objects Below, but nothing happens. I  get the message, "The  filter cannot complete because more than one object is selected." I only have the two anchors from the object selected, so I am lost.

I do not want to remove the anchors, just have the path of two between removed, and reconnect to a different anchor. [image: This] This image shows what I want to do in  illustrator CS6.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty difficult to make heads or tales of your image. The general procedure to remove a **section** of a path is as follows....

- Deselect all <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Select the Direct Selection Tool (the White Arrow) <kbd>a</kbd>
- Click the section of the path you want to remove
- hit the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key

The Pathfinder operation are for shapes, not anchors or paths, but full shapes. And they only work when more than one *shape* is selected. The name "pathfinder" is a bit misleading. In reality Pathfinder is more "shapefinder" than anything.

Comment: The problem is when I delete the two anchors the entire object gets filled- starting to think photoshop will be the easy way out .

Comment: The steps I provided above will not delete anchors. It will delete the path section connecting those anchors, but leave the anchors. And honestly, for path operations Photoshop is **never** an easier solution.

Comment: Thank you! I am so foolish. I was zoomed into my object and I assumed the whole object disappeared. Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: While you must use the Pathfinder tools with at least with one shape, you can use them with paths in some useful ways. For example, draw a straight line across a circle, select both the line and the circle, then use the Pathfinder->Divide tool. You'll be left with two parts of a circle and no line. Very useful! (For anybody who comes across this, not necessarily directed at you.)

Comment: It isnt obvious that the path is selected when you select the path (at least in CS3), but if it's on a curve you'll see the bezier handles appear on the anchors.